# Cannot find module 'lodash' after running npm install

Tags: node.js, npm

When I run

```
 npm install lodash
```

it comes back with no errors and I can see the lodash folder in my node_modules folder. However, when I then try to run the code using

```
npm run
```

it gives me an error that it 'Cannot find module 'lodash''.

The file is included using the code

```
var _ = require('lodash');
```

I'm using node.js version 6.2.1, upgraded from version 4.4.5 where I had the same problem. This seems to be a problem just for me, someone else has installed the code without getting this problem. I can also perform other installs without any problems. I've tried deleting the node_modules folder and cleaning the npm cache but neither made any difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: in my node_modules — where is it? Show full paths to lodash and file that requires it

Comment: what happens if you install lodash globally?